# I am having trouble with Google Map Api Zoom in to fit all the markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have herewith attached the source code of the google API i am using. I have created a array which contains a list of the markers i want to view. I found a link (http://blog.shamess.info/2009/09/29/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-maps-api-v3/) online that shows me that i can use the fit bound method to view all the markers. I tried implementing it but instead of being able to view all markers but before i could view all the markers and now i can't view any. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me here . I am very new to js so please forgive me if i have made a really silly mistake.

```
function initApp() {
APIKey = {
'bing': '',
'leaflet': ''
};

console.log('app initialized');
startGeolocation();

 }


 /**
  *  google maps
   */

  // initialize the map
   function initGoogleMaps() {
    myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong);

   var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: myLocation,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoomControl: true,
mapTypeControl: false,
streetViewControl: false
 };
 googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    // search for nearby places
        function initGooglePlaces() {
       //searchForPlaces(googlePlacesCallback);
         findMe();

          }

         // search callback
            function googlePlacesCallback(results) {
          for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createGoogleMarker(results[i]);
      }
           }

           // create a marker / push-pin
            function createGoogleMarker(place) {
         var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: googleMap,
      position: place.geometry.location
          });
           }


        function multiMe(){ }
function findMe() {
var multiArray = new Array (5);
multiArray [0] = new Array(2);
multiArray [1] = new Array(2);
multiArray [2] = new Array(2);
multiArray [3] = new Array(2);
multiArray [4] = new Array(2);  
multiArray [0][0] = "43.9651";
multiArray [0][1] = "-78.8917";
multiArray [1][0] = "43.9551";
multiArray [1][1] = "-78.8917";
multiArray [2][0] = "43.9451";
multiArray [2][1] = "-78.8917";
multiArray [3][0] = "43.9351";
multiArray [3][1] = "-78.8917";
multiArray [4][0] = "43.951";
multiArray [4][1] = "-78.8917";
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    var tLat =  multiArray [i][0];
    var tLong = multiArray [i][1];
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(tLat,tLong );
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    bounds.extend (newLatLng[i]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: googleMap,
        position: newLatLng
    });
    map.fitBounds (bounds);
}
     }
         /**
          * search for POI
          */

       // example of seraching for places using google
      function searchForPlaces(callback) {
     var request = {
      location: myLocation,
      radius: 2000,
       types: ['bar']
       };

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(googleMap);
        service.search(request, callback);
        return;
        }

      /**
        *  geolocation
        */

       // we use HTML5 Geolocation to pin-point where the user is
      function startGeolocation() {
       var options;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFail, options);
        }

        // geolocation success callback
        function geoSuccess(position) {
         var gpsPosition = position;
        var coordinates = gpsPosition.coords;
        myLat = coordinates.latitude;
        myLong = coordinates.longitude;
        bb.pushScreen('google.html', 'google');
        }

        // geolocation failure callback
        function geoFail() {
       alert('Error getting your position. Using defaults instead');

         // set default position upon failure
       myLat = 44.465187;
       myLong = -80.522372;
       bb.pushScreen('google.html', 'google');
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of google.maps.LatLngBounds as a rectangle (4 latitude-longitude coordinates determining it edges). When you call bounds.extend(location), you are changing the edges of the bounds so that the location is included in the rectangle. In your case you need to change

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
var tLat =  multiArray [i][0];
var tLong = multiArray [i][1];
var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(tLat,tLong );
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
bounds.extend (newLatLng[i]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: googleMap,
    position: newLatLng

});
```

with

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
var tLat =  multiArray [i][0];
var tLong = multiArray [i][1];
var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(tLat,tLong );
bounds.extend (newLatLng[i]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: googleMap,
    position: newLatLng

});
```